# FBSDK Can't read profile informations, application ignores the algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My app has the FBSDK to Login and get informations of user profile. The login works nice, but in some places that I want to get user informations, my app simply ignores code and jump to next lines.

This is my login algorithm:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                // Do work
            }
        }
    }];
```

Its work perfectly, my problem is when I try to get the name of current User with the algorithm below:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                 _myUserName = result[@"name"];



             }



         }];
    }
```

using the debug I noticed that the app simply ignore this part of the code .

Is there something I 'm missing or doing wrong?

[EDITED]

The login does not work too... using NSLogs below, none of them were printed in the console.

```
if (error) {
            // Process error
            NSLog(@"1");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
            NSLog(@"2");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"3");
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                // Do work
                NSLog(@"4");
            }
        }
```

[EDITED2]

Looking at Facebook iOS SDK FAQ & Troubleshooting I Found this solution

"FBSDKRequestConnection uses NSURLConnection which requires an active RunLoop. If you're using it outside of the main thread you have to manage this yourself.

Alternatively, you can set the delegateQueue property on the FBSDKRequestConnection."

So, I just use

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mySelector) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And now it's OK!. Thanks!

Comment: it must be printing something in console. Check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the upgrade guide to v4.0 of the iOS SDK, you should not use the `/me` call anymore. Instead, just use `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]`. That said, the code you're using should also work. Have you put breakpoints into it to see which part is actually being skipped?

Comment: in fact the login does not work ... when it calls the " logInWithReadPermissions : " simply skips the handler block..

Comment: if that is the case, something else is wrong with your app. Did you go through the guide in the Facebook documentation? If you did not set up the SDK right (with your app keys and etc), it won't work.